# How to make a table follow the css of the layout?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

Is there a way to make a table (inside a DIV layout) follow the CSS of that DIV layout? Or do I have to actually add a table code to the CSS? I don't really understand why the table, in this case, the table is inside the content area, but it doesn't use the same font style, colour, size, or anything.

The links inside the table however, do follow the CSS, but nothing else does. How do I make the rest of the text follow the layout's CSS? And if I have to add CSS for the table, what do I add? I don't know anything about table CSS.

You can view the table and all [here](http://takaya.aloveletter.co.uk/list.php?sort=country&name=United%20States).

Comment: Would you like an example of a table done in CSS?

Comment: Seems you are annoyed with the css table :P . Following link might be helpful for you: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: That website is the best, it should help you but if you struggle just ask :)

Comment: So there's no way to just get it to follow the CSS without adding the table coding?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want tables to inherit its parent div style then you might need to change Markup as per below post -

**[Making HTML Tables Inherit Parent Styles](http://ratfactor.com/solution-html-table-style-inherit)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

**Note:** But It is XHTML markup and no longer recommended over HTML5. so Please be sure whether you really want to use this solution.

Hope this helps!